# I've 25 new reputation but label shows "+18"

Tags: support, reputation, top-bar

I've 18 new reputation points but if I look to the achievements and I take the sum of the new reputation I've got 5 + 10 + 6 + 4 = 25. Is there an error happens or is this normal?

[image: new reputation]

Comment: The ajax popup can contain newer information that the achievements box doesn't yet show (especially if the websocket connection got lost). Also, stuff gets aggregated; you probably got +7 points in votes on those documentation posts before.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation votes are *aggregated* into one entry. So the 'missing' +7 is in documentation contribution votes you already were notified about before.

You must've last looked at your achievements between 14:00 and 19:53 UTC. By 14:00, you had received +2 from *HTML output from web server* and +5 from *Getting Started* (each a +1 per vote). At this point, you had 3072 reputation.

From 19:53 until midnight, you received another +2 on *HTML output from web server* and +1 on *Getting Started*. Together with the +5 and +10 reputation events on your question-and-answer pair, that's the +18 you see in the achievements icon badge.